# How to retain whitespace for python in Intellij idea

Tags: intellij-idea, whitespace

I want to retain a space character on only the blank lines between code segments of a single function. The reason is that when cut/paste into interpreter, it will break if no space there (says unexpected indentation).

So I want intellij to not strip out that space character. But I can not find setting to prevent the extra whitespace removal.

here is the use case:

```
def myfunc():
  print "something"

  def internal_Func_that_I_want_separated_by_newline():
    print "how to have a line above this one that includes a single space?"

  def anotherfunc():
    print "foobar"

  foobar()
  internal_Func_that_I_want_separated_by_newline()
```

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set `Editor` | `Strip trailing spaces on save` to **None**. Here is [the screenshot of the option](http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/3746/20130601084118.png).